# Incrementing from the previous value sql

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

So I work on BigQuery, this query is a scheluded one, so it's creates a new table for the first time and after it append to it. So this query add 1 each times the conditions are verified. This query is executed each hour, so each hour I keep data from the last entire hour.

So you may ask what I want, so it's simple I want to keep the last value of this counter and from this one executes this script and append to it for each row.

Here is my actual code :

```
SELECT
  Date,
sum(
  CASE
    WHEN B > 1 THEN ---Vérification si le capteur est fiable
      CASE
        WHEN A>1 THEN ---Cas numéro 1
          CASE
            WHEN A < (B * (1 + 0.05)) AND A > (B * (1 - 0.05)) THEN 1
          END
        WHEN C>1 THEN ---Cas numéro 2
          CASE
            WHEN E>1 THEN  ---Si la donnée est fiable
              CASE
                WHEN (C+E) < (B * (1 + 0.05)) AND (C+E) > (B * (1 - 0.05)) THEN 1
              END
            ELSE --- Si elle ne l'est pas
              CASE
                WHEN D >= 0 AND F>= 0 AND G>=0  THEN ---On vérifie que toutes ces données sont >= 0
                  CASE
                    WHEN (C+(D+F+G)) < (B * (1 + 0.05)) AND (C+(D+F+G)) > (B * (1 - 0.05)) THEN 1
                  END
                ELSE  ---Si elles ne le sont pas
                  CASE
                    WHEN (C+0) < (B * (1 + 0.05)) AND (C+0) > (B * (1 - 0.05)) THEN 1
                  END
              END
          END
        WHEN E>1 THEN  ---Cas numéro 3
          CASE
            WHEN D>=0 AND G >= 0 AND F>=0 THEN ---On vérifie que toutes ces données sont >= 0
              CASE
                WHEN (E + (G+D+F)) < (B * (1 + 0.05)) AND (E + (G+D+F)) > (B * (1 - 0.05)) THEN 1
              END
            ELSE
              CASE
                WHEN (E + 0) < (B * (1 + 0.05)) AND (E + 0) > (B * (1 - 0.05)) THEN 1
              END
          END
      END
  END) over(over by Date) AS Cpt,
 
FROM
  my_table
---WHERE DATETIME_DIFF(CAST("2020-05-11 21:00:00" AS DATETIME),DATETIME(Date),HOUR)<=1 AND DATETIME_DIFF(CAST("2020-05-11 21:00:00" AS DATETIME),DATETIME(Date),SECOND) > 1
```

I want the final table like this

```
First Hour :
+---------+---------+
| columnA | counter |
+---------+---------+
| 1       | 1       | <= Match condition 
+---------+---------+
| 2       | 2       | <= Match condition 
+---------+---------+
| 3       | 2       | <= Don't Match condition 
+---------+---------+
| 4       | 3       | <= Match condition 
+---------+---------+

Second hour :
+---------+---------+
| columnA | counter |
+---------+---------+
| 1       | 1       | <= Match condition 
+---------+---------+
| 2       | 2       | <= Match condition 
+---------+---------+
| 3       | 2       | <= Don't Match condition 
+---------+---------+
| 4       | 3       | <= Match condition 
+---------+---------+
| 5       | 4       | <= Match condition, the second iteration begin here, want to keep the last value of the counter and add frome this one
+---------+---------+
| 6       | 5       | <= Match condition 
+---------+---------+
| 7       | 6       | <= Match condition 
+---------+---------+
| 8       | 6       | <= Don't Match condition 
+---------+---------+
```

**EDIT** :
Sample Data :

```
FIRST INPUT TABLE :
+-------------------------+--------+------+--------+---+-----+---+-----+
| Date                    | A      | B    | C      | D | E   | F | G   |
+-------------------------+--------+------+--------+---+-----+---+-----+
| 2020-05-11 00:00:00 UTC | 37.696 | 38.0 | 35.358 | 0 | 1.5 | 0 | 1.5 |
+-------------------------+--------+------+--------+---+-----+---+-----+
| 2020-05-11 00:01:00 UTC | 38.257 | 38.0 | 35.935 | 0 | 1.5 | 0 | 1.5 |
+-------------------------+--------+------+--------+---+-----+---+-----+
| 2020-05-11 00:02:00 UTC | 38.571 | 38.0 | 36.242 | 0 | 1.5 | 0 | 1.5 |
+-------------------------+--------+------+--------+---+-----+---+-----+
| 2020-05-11 00:03:00 UTC | 38.01  | 38.0 | 35.687 | 0 | 1.5 | 0 | 1.5 |
+-------------------------+--------+------+--------+---+-----+---+-----+

(1 HOUR LATER) SECOND INPUT :

+-------------------------+--------+------+--------+---+-----+---+-----+
| Date                    | A      | B    | C      | D | E   | F | G   |
+-------------------------+--------+------+--------+---+-----+---+-----+
| 2020-05-11 01:00:00 UTC | 40.297 | 38.0 | 37.97  | 0 | 1.5 | 0 | 1.5 |
+-------------------------+--------+------+--------+---+-----+---+-----+
| 2020-05-11 01:01:00 UTC | 40.297 | 38.0 | 37.97  | 0 | 1.5 | 0 | 1.5 |
+-------------------------+--------+------+--------+---+-----+---+-----+
| 2020-05-11 01:02:00 UTC | 40.297 | 38.0 | 37.97  | 0 | 1.5 | 0 | 1.5 |
+-------------------------+--------+------+--------+---+-----+---+-----+
| 2020-05-11 01:03:00 UTC | 40.297 | 38.0 | 36.881 | 0 | 1.5 | 0 | 1.5 |
+-------------------------+--------+------+--------+---+-----+---+-----+
```

**2nd EDIT** : I found the solution for my case, I've just put all of my algorithm into a WITH and After I did a select and I did the sum of the max of my previous counter and the actual.

Comment: you do not explain you problem yet!

Comment: How i thought I did, but in fact I have 2 table, the first one is where I get the data and the second one is where I put the result. For each row that match the condition a counter increase by 1 okay ? This script is called every one hour, so I want the scrips take the last value of the counter in my output table and begin from this point and append the new row with the right value of the counter.

Comment: Please add some sample data with your expected output. That would help.

Comment: It's done mate  .

Comment: Still some data is missing I guess. Who is matching with whom? where from second iteration coming?

Comment: When I write "matching" condition it just mean that the condition is reached noting more, whatever the condition, what I want it's just the way to increment just after the last value when I call my query again

Comment: You can use a condition like - CASE WHEN "Matched THEN (SELECT MAX(value) + 1 FROM your_table) ELSE (SELECT MAX(value) FROM your_table) END

Comment: I already tried it but it do the sum with the max at each row so for exemple I have result like 58 for the row 32 and 116 for the row 33 or I just want to have 59 for the row 33

Comment: Thats why I am asking for sample data with your table structure (with necessary columns) :)

Comment: I've added the input table